# Why is AES encrypted cipher of the same string with the same key always different?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes

I have a file called plain.txt. Inside the file I have:

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

I am using this command to encrypt it:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
```

Then I print the encrypted value like this:

```
buff = open("encrypted.bin")
cipher = buff.read()
buff.close()
print b64encode(cipher)
```

But it is always different value. Shouldn't the cipher be always the same? I am using the same file and the same password to encrypt it. These are my terminal outputs:

```
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ python test.py U2FsdGVkX1+AmoQiIkYAxIYanLr/kbjMfEJPPLfeE/wtyxScvAKzb7K38ZxoI097
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ python test.py U2FsdGVkX19vPD+OoiK7iSgYJiPMxuKGNWWrLlfBS0c3yCJkuv7QIBGEo2Q86UsV
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$ python test.py U2FsdGVkX1+3I8EC7u3lrcVPyD/JV12NAecWvTPXGga0Nh2cwqLAtGCDhLK6MI9g
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:python_test richardknop$
```

Comment: Basically, the cipher text should always look as a random output. If it doesn't, it leaks information. In this case, you could see if an encryption with the same password start with an identical value previously encrypted. Imagine the following conversation: are you general BadEncryption? Encrypted answer: "yes". Should we attack at dawn? Encrypted answer: "yes". So the foe sees the encrypted but identical messages and starts to man the howitzers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the "salt" varies each time. This prevents, for example, rainbow table type attacks on the encrypted values. See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)

Comment: Can I encrypt it without using salt? What is the parameter?

Comment: You can use -nosalt. But it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting different encrypted string is " enc -aes-128-cbc".
CBC stands for Cipher Block Chaining. So, for 2nd block, the encrypted output of first block acts ac IV, so each time you get different string.
for more details google "AES in CBC mode"

Answer (score 0):

You get different outputs on each run because new salt is generated each time you run the command. In order to provide the same salt for each consecutive run use `-S salt` option, i.e.

```sh
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -S "Salt" -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the actual `key` which is used for encryption is driven from your `passphrase` and the `SALT`. Then definitely the ciphertext will be different even if you still use the same password because the `SALT` is different.

Openssl uses salt by default to mitigate dictionary attacks. If you don't want to use it then use same salt as suggested by other answers, or add `nosalt` option as follow:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -k "Hello" -in plain.txt -out encrypted.bin
```

You can see the ciphertext in hex using `xxd`

```
xxd encrypted.bin
```